Select one of several subattributes dependent on its content
I have a JSON Output describing the configuration of an OPNSense Firewall.
I want to condense the output into something more useful. Consider the following element of a list of VLANs
[
  {
    "key": "0eb660b0-555a-469e-be04-8c3584108f9b",
    "value": {
      "if": {
        "igb1": {
          "value": "igb1 (64:62:66:22:6e:d0) [UNTAGGED]",
          "selected": 0
        },
        "igb2": {
          "value": "igb2 (64:62:66:22:6e:d1) [tagged]",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "tag": "20",
      "pcp": {
        "1": {
          "value": "Background (1, lowest)",
          "selected": 0
        },
        "0": {
          "value": "Best Effort (0, default)",
          "selected": 1
        },
        "2": {
          "value": "Excellent Effort (2)",
          "selected": 0
        }
      },
      "proto": {
        "": {
          "value": "Auto",
          "selected": 1
        },
        "802.1q": {
          "value": "802.1Q",
          "selected": 0
        },
        "802.1ad": {
          "value": "802.1ad",
          "selected": 0
        }
      },
      "descr": "USERS: PCs und Handies  ",
      "vlanif": "vlan0.20"
    }
  }
]


I would like to see only the content for if, pcp or proto, which have selected ==1. Whether I get their key or their value is anther problem.  The result could look like this:
[
  {
    "key": "0eb660b0-555a-469e-be04-8c3584108f9b",
    "value": {
      "if": {
        "igb2": {
          "value": "igb2 (64:62:66:22:6e:d1) [tagged]",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "tag": "20",
      "pcp": {
        "0": {
          "value": "Best Effort (0, default)",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "proto": {
        "": {
          "value": "Auto",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "descr": "USERS: PCs und Handies  ",
      "vlanif": "vlan0.20"
    }
  }
]


See online
I tried all variants of select which occured to me. But i don't know how to select a subattribute and not the whole object.

Traverse to each potential object, e.g. using .[].value["if", "pcp", "proto"], and update its items using either map_values or another level of iteration (reliable since jq 1.7) by filtering for their items that match the condition, .selected == 1 in this case:
.[].value["if", "pcp", "proto"] |= map_values(select(.selected == 1))
# or
.[].value["if", "pcp", "proto"][] |= select(.selected == 1)

[
  {
    "key": "0eb660b0-555a-469e-be04-8c3584108f9b",
    "value": {
      "if": {
        "igb2": {
          "value": "igb2 (64:62:66:22:6e:d1) [tagged]",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "tag": "20",
      "pcp": {
        "0": {
          "value": "Best Effort (0, default)",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "proto": {
        "": {
          "value": "Auto",
          "selected": 1
        }
      },
      "descr": "USERS: PCs und Handies  ",
      "vlanif": "vlan0.20"
    }
  }
]

Demo 1,
Demo 2
